# How to access azure table storage using REST API in .Net Core

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to access data from azure table storage ,but i couldn't access using Net core .But it's possible using .Net Framework.

Below code was written in .Net Framework

```
var sharedKey = Convert.FromBase64String("AccountKey");
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://accountname.table.core.windows.net/tablename");
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var resource = request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
        if (resource.Contains("?"))
        {
            resource = resource.Substring(0, resource.IndexOf("?"));
        }

        string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n/{1}{2}",
                request.Headers["x-ms-date"],
                 "accountname",
                resource
            );
        var hasher = new HMACSHA256(sharedKey);
        string signedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
        string authorizationHeader = string.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKeyLite", "accountname", signedSignature);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        return response;
```

Comment: Why not use the Storage SDK that support .NET Core as well ?
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net

Comment: Here is how to use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are some differences between .Net Core and .Net Standard when using REST API.

1. In .NET 4.5 there are some properties you have to set on the
   HttpWebRequest object and you can’t just set them in the headers.
   Well, in core they decided to reverse course and you have to use the
   header collection.

   .NET Core: 
   `request.Headers["x-ms-version"] = "2015-04-05";`

   .NET 4.5:
   `request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-04-05");`
2. .NET  Core only support WebResponse.GetResponseAsync() method, so
   you could only use the async way to get the result.

   Like below:
   `Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync();
   HttpWebResponse responseresult = (HttpWebResponse)response.Result;`

More details, you could refer to follow codes:

```
string storageAccount = "storageAccount";
        string accessKey = "accessKey";
        string resourcePath = "TableSample()";
        string uri = @"https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/" + resourcePath;
        // Web request 
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=nometadata";
        request.Headers["x-ms-date"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        request.Headers["x-ms-version"] = "2015-04-05";
        string stringToSign = request.Headers["x-ms-date"] + "\n"; 
        int query = resourcePath.IndexOf("?");
        if (query > 0)
        {
            resourcePath = resourcePath.Substring(0, query);
        }
        stringToSign += "/" + storageAccount + "/" + resourcePath;
        System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 hasher = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(accessKey));
        string strAuthorization = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));


        request.Headers["Authorization"] = strAuthorization;

        Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync();
        HttpWebResponse responseresult = (HttpWebResponse)response.Result;

            using (System.IO.StreamReader r = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseresult.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string jsonData = r.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(jsonData);
           }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: the above code is not working in .Net Core ,because of `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256`  reference not found in .Net Core

Comment: As far as I know, the .Net Core will automatic installed the package System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms. I suggest you could follow below way to add refernce: Right click the Application name --> Manage Nuget Packages ---> Search the System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms and install it.